# Google Cloud Slides API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

im trying to figure out how to edit a google slides via the python api, but im getting auth scope errors,

```hs
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/1Sqc7C8q2bF1Ay65sO-nZgEJNGuzGBgXIpxqv7hc4v6g:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'slides.googleapis.com', 'method': 'google.apps.slides.v1.PresentationsService.BatchUpdatePresentation'}}]">
```

('reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT')

my code used to do this was the following:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import os.path
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

import json

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly']

# The ID of a sample presentation.
PRESENTATION_ID = 'LEWL'

creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

#

# Add a slide at index 1 using the predefined
# 'TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS' layout and the ID page_id.
requests = [
    {
        'createSlide': {
            'objectId': 'titlepage',
            'insertionIndex': '1',
            'slideLayoutReference': {
                'predefinedLayout': 'TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS'
            }
        }
    }
]

# If you wish to populate the slide with elements,
# add element create requests here, using the page_id.

# Execute the request.
body = {
    'requests': requests
}
response = service.presentations() \
    .batchUpdate(presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID, body=body).execute()
create_slide_response = response.get('replies')[0].get('createSlide')
print(f"Created slide with ID:"
      f"{(create_slide_response.get('objectId'))}")
```

also, im not sure how to modfiy scopes, so if thats the issue advice would be much appreciated

also one thing to mention is that i can read data from google slides with no issues, but editing doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT` means:

> The request is denied because the provided access token doesn't have
> at least one of the acceptable scopes required for the API

The scope defined in your code is:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly']
```

From [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#slides)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly -    See all your Google Slides presentations
```

To edit slides, the request should have following scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations   See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Slides presentations
```

To modify the scope, change the SCOPE variables as follows:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations']
```